# ufw rule not reflected in firewalld

Tags: ufw, firewalld

I have allowed connection from anywhere to anyport using ufw:

`sudo ufw allow from any`

When I try to reach a service I still get blocked, I receive `No route to host` but if i disable firewalld then I can reach the service.

Why is the firewall not updated.